# How to sending mail with javamail 1.5.1 using a microsoft exchange server?

Tags: java, email, servlets, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I've passed my day to search how sending mail with javamail 1.5.1 using microsoft exchange server and i didn't found a solution for my project.

```
  public static void sendMail(String message_dest,String message_objet,String message_corps){

  Authenticator auth;
  Session session;
  Message mesg;

  Properties props = new Properties();

  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.X.X.X");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

  //Authenticator auth = new MyAuthentificator();
  auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        return new PasswordAuthentication(
           "xx@xx.com", "xx");
     }
  };

  session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

  session.setDebug(true);

  try {
     mesg = new MimeMessage(session);

     mesg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(xx@xx.com));

     InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(message_dest);
     mesg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

     mesg.setSubject(message_objet);

     mesg.setText(message_corps);

     Transport.send(mesg);

  } catch (MessagingException ex) {
     while ((ex = (MessagingException)ex.getNextException()) != null) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

I've already try to move out my authentification in an other class but it won't work too...

Please help :(

PS: Sorry for my english...

Comment: You didn't provide any information about how it's not working so it's hard to guess what's going wrong.  Maybe you didn't provide the correct username or password?  Start by cleaning up these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), then post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
    import javax.activation.DataHandler;
    import javax.activation.DataSource;
    import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
    import javax.mail.BodyPart;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

    public class EmailSenderWWOAttachment {

    private static final int MSGCOUNT = 10;
    static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
    static Session session;

    static class Sender implements Runnable {
        @Override

        public void run() {
            while(c.get()<MSGCOUNT){
                int  i = c.incrementAndGet();
                try {
                    // email without attachment
                    MimeMessage msg1 = new MimeMessage(session);
                    msg1.setFrom("mailbox1@abc.com");
                    msg1.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "mailbox2@abc.com");
                    msg1.setSubject("Subject of email: " + i);
                    msg1.setText("Body of email: " + i);
                    Transport.send(msg1);
                    System.out.println("Email no. " + i + " without attachment sent");

                    // email with attachment
                    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                    msg.setFrom("mailbox3@abc.com");
                    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "mailbox4@abc.com");
                    msg.setSubject("Subject of email: " + i);
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart.setText("Body of email: " + i);
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                    BodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    String filename = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\1.txt";
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                    attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    attachBodyPart.setFileName("1.txt");
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
                    msg.setContent(multipart);
                    Transport.send(msg);
                    System.out.println("Email no. " + i + " with attachment sent");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    c.decrementAndGet();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put( "mail.smtp.host", "exchange-server" );
        session = Session.getInstance( props, null );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 20 );
        for( int i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
            executorService.execute( new Sender() );
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentification in your option talib2608 :( But I looked at these links and now my authentication works fine. (thanks bill shannon)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug

```
   public static void sendMail(String message_dest,String message_objet,String message_corps){

  Authenticator auth;
  Session session;
  Message mesg;

  Properties props = new Properties();

  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT1);
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST1);
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

  session = Session.getInstance(props);

  session.setDebug(true); 

  try {
     mesg = new MimeMessage(session);

     mesg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(IMAP_ACCOUNT1));

     InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(message_dest);
     mesg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

     mesg.setSubject(message_objet);

     mesg.setText(message_corps);

     Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
     try {
         t.connect("xx@xx.com", "mypwd");
         t.sendMessage(mesg, mesg.getAllRecipients());
     } finally {
         t.close();
     }

  }catch (MessagingException ex){
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
}
```

But when I try it, i don't receive my message...

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xx.xx.xxx.xx", port 25, isSSL true
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xx.xx.xxx.xx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

This error message comes when i test on my local machine, not on the server.